# How to Archive only todays file

Tags: shell, unix, unix-timestamp, aix

I have a script, it is getting the list of files from the list file and sending those files a server using SCP and then Archiving those files.

I need to modify it, so that it works on only the files WHICH ARE CREATED TODAY ( Then the Script is ran ) !

Here is my code -

```
    exec 1> $CODE/WCC_FOA_RMBHUB/logs/rmb_to_afbs_ftp_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log 2>&1

    . $CODE/WCC_FOA_RMBHUB/parms/RMB_To_AFBS.parm

    ListFilePath=$CODE/WCC_FOA_RMBHUB/lists
    TgtFilePath=$PMDIR/TgtFiles/WCC_FOA_RMBHUB
    ArchivePath=$PMDIR/SrcFiles/WCC_FOA_RMBHUB/Archives
    Today=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

    MasterAfbsFile=Master_File_RMB_To_AFBS.lst

    while read TrgtFileName
    do

    ZippedFile=$TrgtFileName'.gz.'$Today
    if [ -f $TgtFilePath/$TrgtFileName ]
    then
    echo AFBS Target File $TrgtFileName is available in the path $TgtFilePath

##### NED TO ADD SOME IF CONDITION HERE TO CHECK IF THE FILE IS HAVING TODAYS DATE OR NOT ######

    echo Performing SCP
    scp $TgtFilePath/$TrgtFileName $USER_ID@$MACHINE:..$DIRNAME

                            if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                                    then
                                    echo "ERROR while trying to move the $TrgtFileName to FTP bridge path"
                                    exit $? ;
                                    else
                                    echo scp command executed successfully
                                    echo "File $TrgtFileName is moved to the archival path"
                                    gzip -c $TgtFilePath/$TrgtFileName > $ArchivePath/$ZippedFile
                                    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                                    then
                                    echo "ERROR while trying to move the $TrgtFileName to Archival path"
                                    exit $? ;
                                    else
                                    echo "File Archival Successful"
                                    rm $TgtFilePath/$TrgtFileName
                                    fi
                            fi

    else
    echo AFBS target File $TrgtFileName is not available in the path $TgtFilePath
    fi

    done <$ListFilePath/$MasterAfbsFile
```

I have tried to look for file date using Grep and Find command, but i am not able to land upon a perfect dynamic solution, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: added explanation (requested in comment)

Use touch -t YYMMDDHHMM.SS for a referencefile at midnight:

`touch -t $(date +%Y%m%d0000.00) /tmp/archive_date.tmp
find $TgtFilePath -type f -newer /tmp/archive_date.tmp`

With find and -mtime you can select files less than a day old. This is not a solution, it will look back 24 hours.
After the touch /tmp/archive_date.tmp will be from last midnight. With find you can look for files that are newer than a give file. The find will show the files from today. I added -type f, we are not interested in directories.

In your code you are using Master_File_RMB_To_AFBS.lst for a 'whitelist' of files to be processed. Now you have 2 lists, the find output and your 'whitelist'. I think you only want files that are present in both files.
Finding lines that are shared in 2 files is possible with `common -12` when both files are sorted first. Using sort + common should be the best solution for large filesets, but you need 2 additional tmp files (the sorted files) *)
*) In bash you can use process substition with <<< avoiding the tmp files.

The solution beneath alse works when the paths given by the find are relative paths and the files in Master_File_RMB_To_AFBS.lst complete paths.

Looping through the output of a command can be done with
`for file in $(command); do`
and with
`command | while read file; do`
I prefer the last method for some reasons:

- command can return an empty string
  The while will put nothing in the pipe, nothing goes wrong here. The for will result in a incomplete line.
- I have learned to read from left to right, pipes feel natural.
- While reads complete lines
  for will break the input on spaces (or what your IFS says)
- While can split inputlines in words / different vars
  Not used here, would be something like `while read field1 f2 f3 f_others`

Inside the loop, with a $file found by the find command, you want to check the file with Master_File_RMB_To_AFBS.lst. You only need to know  if the file is found. I do not use `grep -q`, this is not supported by all grep's. So I use the count option -c.
myAction is about everything you have written in your question while-loop.
When you want to make a function of it, you must choose how the function knows the $file. Just pick it up is possible (using it as a global var), but the preferred technique is given it as a parameter `myFunction "$file"` and reading the parameter in myFunction.

This will result in:

When you want to check your $MasterAfbsFile file, you can make a loop like

```
find $TgtFilePath -type f -newer /tmp/archive_date.tmp | while read file; do
   if [ $(grep -c "${file}" ${MasterAfbsFile}) -gt 0 ]; then
      myAction "${file}"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Hi file is having the file name with the complete path and so it is not able to GREP it in the Masterfile and hence it is always going out of if. Can you solve this thing ? Thansk

Comment: When you do not want to edit the masterfile (not afraid for files with the same name in different folders), you can use the `basename ${file}` or use `${file##*/}`.  No time now to edit my answer with this.

Comment: Thanks for the Solutiion. I can take it from here and modify the script accordingly.